# Toggle background image when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I need the background image of list items toggled when check box is checked.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="yes" id="answer" name="answer" data-label="I am over the age of 18" />
<div class="categories row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <ul>
            <li>Full Name</li>
            <li>Current Address</li>
            <li>Address History</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.span12 -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.categories ul li {
    background:url(http://s21.postimg.org/j4dl4r30z/pretty_Checkbox.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    padding-left:30px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    $('.categories ul li').css("background-position", "0px -32px");  
});
```

This is not working, I'm not sure if it has syntax errors.

I created a jsFiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/kikix2125/McLeC/

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`?

Comment: He meant he did not include jQuery to the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

How about a css way and a toggle class:

CSS:

```
.categories ul li {
    background:url(http://s21.postimg.org/j4dl4r30z/pretty_Checkbox.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    padding-left:30px;
    list-style:none;
}
.categories ul li.active{
   background-position: 0px -32px;
}
```

JS:

```
  $('.checkbox').click(function(){
     $('.categories ul li').toggleClass("active");  
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zH45N/)**

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're targeting versions of IE before 9 you don't need any JavaScript to do this; just use the [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked):

```
.categories li {
  background: url(http://s21.postimg.org/j4dl4r30z/pretty_Checkbox.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

#answer:checked + .categories li {
  background-position: 0px -32px;
}
```

[Take a look at the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrunning/8ms5N/).